# Eliminar numeros no repetidos de un arreglo

Tags: java

tengo un arreglo con estos elementos; arr = {1,2,2,3}, quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar con eliminar los elementos no repetidos quedando asi: arr = {2};

He intentado usando variaciones de este codigo.

**

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
                    if(i != j)
                    {
                        if(!c[i].equals(c[j]))
                        {
                            c[i]=" ";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                aux = aux+", "+c[i];
            }
        }
        return aux;
```

**

Comment: Ejemplo. Este programa recibe un String, c = {"1","2","2","3"}, solo quiero que elimine los que no son repetidos o en otras palabras que deje los que se repiten, c = {"2","2"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé qué hice, pero funciona.
El primer bloque de for detecta cuáles datos están repetidos, guarda cada uno de ellos en el array "**d**" por ejemplo: el valor 2 está repetido por lo que guarda un 2 dentro del array. Después, en el segundo bloque de for verifica si la posición [0],[1],[2]... contiene alguno de los datos repetidos del array "**d**", si es así, la variable "**contains**" será true, lo que hará que el if de debajo esté permitido a sobreescribir los datos de aquella posición en "**c[#]**" por "**Nada**", volviendo a la variable contains en *false* por si la siguiente posición no es igual.

```
String[] c = {"1", "2", "2", "3"};
    String[] d = new String[c.length];
    int d_pos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < c.length; j++) {
            if (c[i].equals(c[j])) {
                // Si el dato está duplicado:
                d[d_pos] = c[j];
                d_pos++;
            }
        }
    }

    boolean contains = false;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
            if(c[i].equals(d[j])){
                contains = true;
            }                    
            else {
                
            }  
        }
        if (contains) {
            contains = false;
        } else {
            c[i] = "";
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
        System.out.println("Final " + c[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

No soy experto en Java, pero creo que lo que estás buscando es el clásico uso de un  `set` que existe en casi cualquier lenguaje moderno. Un `set` es un *iterable* (en términos de Python) que contiene valores únicos. En Java existe algo similar.

Checa estos dos recursos:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_set_interface.htm

Suerte